# Why JetpackCompose Material Theme shape is about the edge roundedness?

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

In Jetpack Compose, we can easily define Material Theming for the Color, Typography and Shape.
The one that confuses me is the Shape.

The default shape is

```
val Shapes = Shapes(
    small = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    medium = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
    large = RoundedCornerShape(0.dp)
)
```

Why shape's size is related to corner radius? (e.g. the smaller one is, the more rounded shape?). Any rational behind it

Comment: Shape are defined by Corner and Edge angles and curves. The corners are defined by a shape family (RoundedCorner for example) and a shape size (4.dp for example). All the shapes are grouped into categories (Small components, Medium components,Large components) and for each of them you can define the type of shape.

Comment: Thanks, @GabrieleMariotti. Sorry for not being clear. I understand shape can be defined by how rounded the corner. I'm not sure what is it linked to small, medium, and large... why not primary or secondary? (like color)

Comment: Check this [link](https://material.io/design/shape/applying-shape-to-ui.html#shape-scheme). Each component is classified under a category. For example in the `Button `definition you can find the default: `shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small`

Comment: Nice! That fully explains now, with the link to those components. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Material Design all components are grouped into shape categories based on their size.
[Shape categories include](https://material.io/design/shape/applying-shape-to-ui.html#shape-scheme):

- Small components
- Medium components
- Large components

For each of them you can define the type of shape defining corner and edge angles and curves.The corners are defined by a shape family (`RoundedCorner` for example) and a shape size (`4.dp` for example).
There are some built-in shapes like [`RoundedCornerShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/RoundedCornerShape), [`CutCornerShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/CutCornerShape), [`CircleShape`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/shape/package-summary#circleshape).

**Each component is classified under a category**.
Check this link for [more info](https://material.io/design/shape/applying-shape-to-ui.html#shape-scheme).

For example in the `Button` definition you can find the default:

```
shape: Shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small
```